# Convergence in distribution - using moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_{n1},X_{n2}...X_{nn} $ be independent random variables with a common distribution given as follows:

$P(X_{nk} = 0)= 1 - \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{n^2} \quad,P(X_{nk} = 1)= \dfrac{1}{n} \quad ,P(X_{nk} = 2)=\dfrac{1}{n^2}$

where $k =1,2,...,n$ and $n=2,3...$ Set $S_n = X_{n1} + X_{n2} +...+ X_{nn}$ show that:

$S_n \xrightarrow{d} Po(1) $.

here is  my idea:

$\psi_{X_{nk}}(t) = E[e^{t\cdot X_{nk}}] = 1- \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \dfrac{e^t}{n} + \dfrac{e^{2t}}{n^2}$.

Therefore we get that $\psi_{s_n}(t) =\left( 1- \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \dfrac{e^t}{n} + \dfrac{e^{2t}}{n^2}\right)^n $

Is it possible? to arrange the terms so that one can see that:

$\psi_{S_{n}}(t) \rightarrow  e^{e^t -1}  = \psi_{Po(1)}(t) \quad ,n \rightarrow \infty $

i suspect that there is, but i can't find the way to arrange them

Comment: The problem boils down to evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{n} + \frac{\beta}{n^2}\right)$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Can you handle this?

Comment: @Sasha i still can't see could you elaborate on that a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite the moment-generating function a little
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \psi_{s_n}\left(t\right) &=& \left( 1 + \frac{\exp(t)-1}{n} + \frac{\exp(2t)-1}{n^2} \right)^n = \exp\left( n \ln \left( 1 + \frac{\exp(t)-1}{n} + \frac{\exp(2t)-1}{n^2}  \right)\right) \\ &=& \exp\left( \frac{ \ln \left( 1 + \frac{\exp(t)-1}{n} + \frac{\exp(2t)-1}{n^2}  \right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Denoting $\alpha = \exp(t)-1$ and $\beta = \exp(2t)-1$, we write, using continuity of the exponential function
$$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \psi_{s_n}(t) &=& \exp\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{ \ln \left( 1 + \frac{\alpha}{n} + \frac{\beta}{n^2}  \right)}{\frac{1}{n}} \right) \\
&\stackrel{u=1/n}{=}& \exp\left(\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{ \ln \left( 1 + \alpha u + \beta u^2  \right)}{u} \right) \\
 &\stackrel{\large \mathrm{l'Hospital}}{=}& \exp\left(\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{ \left(\alpha + 2 \beta u\right) / \left( 1 + \alpha u + \beta u^2  \right)}{1} \right) = \exp(\alpha)  \\ &=& \psi_{\mathrm{Poi}(1)}\left(t\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$